# Queiuing Theme - Missing marketplace-portlet

Tags: liferay

I seem to be getting these specific errors when attempting to deploy a custom theme on my Liferay Portal

```
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149059> <Module Peaks-2.0 of
 application Peaks-2.0 is transitioning from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARED on serv
er eportal-DEV01.>
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149060> <Module Peaks-2.0 of
 application Peaks-2.0 successfully transitioned from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARE
D on server eportal-DEV01.>
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149059> <Module Peaks-2.0 of
 application Peaks-2.0 is transitioning from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on se
rver eportal-DEV01.>
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149060> <Module Peaks-2.0 of
 application Peaks-2.0 successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_AD
MIN on server eportal-DEV01.>
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <09:01:01,854 INFO
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']
[HotDeployEvent:130] Plugin Peaks-2.0 requires marketplace-portlet>
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <09:01:01,855 INFO
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']
[HotDeployImpl:252] Queueing Peaks-2.0 for deploy because it is missing marketpl
ace-portlet>
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149059> <Module Peaks-2.0 of
 application Peaks-2.0 is transitioning from STATE_ADMIN to STATE_ACTIVE on serv
er eportal-DEV01.>
<Feb 7, 2014 9:01:01 AM CST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149060> <Module Peaks-2.0 of
 application Peaks-2.0 successfully transitioned from STATE_ADMIN to STATE_ACTIV
E on server eportal-DEV01.>
```

I'm running Liferay EE 6.2 on a WebLogic app server, here are some contents of my portal-ext.properties:

auto.deploy.deploy.dir=/hosting/apps/eportal/autoDeploy
auto.deploy.weblogic.dest.dir=/hosting/apps/eportal/liferayDeployments

I see both marketplace-portlet and my theme in the /liferayDeployments folder, however, neither is not showing up in the portal.

Any ideas as to how to fix this issue?

Attached are some extra portal-ext.properties

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is `/hosting/apps/eportal/liferayDeployments` configured to be monitored by Weblogic, e.g. automatically deployed to the appserver? If not, you might need to deploy them manually, e.g. after Liferay is done with the automatic deployment (injecting dependencies etc.) plugins end up in that directory. If Weblogic doesn't deploy these files on its own, you might need to zip them up as WAR files and deploy them manually.

Tomcat typically does this automatically, but "big iron" Appservers typically don't. The keyword here is "typically" - it all depends on your installation/configuration.

You'll find more about Weblogic installation in the [User's Guide](https://www.liferay.com/en/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/install-liferay-on-weblogic-12c-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-15-en), but - granted - it's quite shallow on the plugins story. I'm mainly linking it here for others that might find this question later.

Comment: Yes Weblogic deploys them automatically to the server. I was thinking that it was my version of marketplace-portlet.war that I'm using but I've tried at least three different ones with all the same result. The current being straight from Liferay's website